# how to change a NCSA squid proxy user password from the client en

Tags: change-password

Here i hv implemented a squid proxy web caching server with NCSA authentication. Proxy users are able to login and accessing the internet. Now client wants to change his proxy password from their end. Any idea regarding that.

Answer (score -2):

```
htpasswd /etc/squid/squid_password name_of_user
```